# Parse Json Object PHP

Tags: php, android, json, parsing, push

I want to parse the following Json-Object:

```
{"multicast_id":123456,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}
```

I was able to succefully parse the values from success, failure, etc, but am having difficulties getting the "error"-msg ("InvalidRegistration").
I access them like this:

```
        $b = json_decode($a, true);
        if($b['success'] == 1){
            $result = true;
        }
```

How do i access the results / error section?

I tried to do it like this:

```
$b['results']['error']
```

but it didn't work.

Thank you for your help, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you use `json_decode` function, a php array will be produced that will have the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [multicast_id] => 123456
    [success] => 0
    [failure] => 1
    [canonical_ids] => 0
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [error] => InvalidRegistration
                )

        )

)
```

which means that in order to access the `error` key inside the `results` array you need to type `$b['results'][0]['error']`. Of course, this is not the optimal way unless you know that there is always going to be one index in the `results` array. In the case where an unknown number of indexes existed (`[0]`, `[1]`, `[2]` ... `[n]`), it would be a better idea to create a loop and go through each of them.